# Servlet running on Tomcat in Eclipse but not displaying on Ubuntu Server Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu-12.04

I have a servlet as follows that is running perfectly on my Eclipse tomcat. When I upload it to the webapps folder and restart my tomcat on my Ubuntu server, the URL for it(/ServerAPP/Login) won't load, though the tomcat root page does fine. If anyone has any idea why this is happening, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and the inner workings of Tomcat so I could have missed anything.
I can give more information on request, I'm just not sure how much is needed, or if there's something simple and stupid I'm not thinking about.

```
package Actions;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/Login"})
public class Login extends HttpServlet implements DataSource {

private String User =  null;
Connection connection = null;
private String password =  null;


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(request.getParameter("User") != null){ 
        this.setUser((String) request.getParameter("User").toString());
    }
    if(request.getParameter("password") != null){
        this.setPassword((String) request.getParameter("password").toString());
    }



    try {
        System.out.println("Loading driver...");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
    }

    Login ds = new Login();
    try {
        connection = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    if(connection != null){

        //out.println(User  + "   " + password);

        //Check if user exists in database
        if(User!= null){

            Statement stmt;
            ResultSet rs;
            try {
                stmt = connection.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE Username = '" + User + "';");


                if(!rs.next()){
                    out.println("Username: " + User + " was not found in Users table.");
                }
                else{
                    //User was found now check if password is correct
                    if(rs.getString(3).equals(password)){
                        out.println("User: " + User + " login successful!");
                    }
                    else if(rs.getString(3).equals(password) == false){
                        //password was incorrect
                        out.println("Password incorrect!");
                    }

                    /*
                    while(rs.next()){
                        out.println("User ID: " + rs.getInt(1) + " Username: " + rs.getString(2));
                    }
                    */

                }

                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                connection.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        /*
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from tblUsers;");
            while(rs.next()){
                out.println("User ID: " + rs.getInt(1) + " Username: " + rs.getString(2));
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */

    }



}



@Override
public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter out) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void setLoginTimeout(int seconds) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public int getLoginTimeout() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


@Override
public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("Cant craete a Connection");
} else {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "<redacted>", "AWSCards", "Cards9876");
}
return connection;
}


@Override
public Connection getConnection(String username, String password)
        throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Cant craete a Connection");
    } else {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "<redacted>", username, password);
    }
    return connection;
}


public String getUser() {
    return User;
}


public void setUser(String user) {
    User = user;
}



public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}



public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Comment: In exception `catch` section add `response.sendError()` and specify all information about the stack trace. Seems that there's a problem with database (connection, etc).

Comment: Well the database returns fine from Eclipse....

Comment: Make sure the database is available from Ubuntu too.

Comment: " the URL for it(/ServerAPP/Login) won't load". Is servlet getting called ? Put some log statements. Provide What is happening when you hit the Url from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out, and I thought it might help others to know. 
Reason:
Apparently, my tomcat on ubuntu was only java 6, while my eclipse was targeting java 7.

Fix:
I went to the project properties and changed the target(which made eclipse mad), but then recompiled it and put it on the tomcat on ubuntu, and it works fine.

Thanks to the people who tried to help me.